# AWS IoT: Possible to connect mobile devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, design-patterns, iot

- Is it possible to programmatically connect a mobile device to IoT in AWS?
- Would the end-user need to do any configuration on their side for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type of device that you have in hand. The device must have a device certificate, private key, and root CA certificate installed for communicating with AWS IoT Core.

There is a SDK that can help you programatically.  The [AWS IoT Device SDKs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/sdk-tutorials.html) help you to connect your devices to AWS IoT. Here is a [list of SDKs](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sdks.html) based on the platform that you are using.

Here is a good link for reference [establishing connection with AWS IoT core service](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/sdk/android/pubsub#establish-connection)